# Target specific resolutions in javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below makes a map expand to a larger size on click, and then return to the previous size on second click. It works great but I want to have the map in different sizes on smaller browsers. My breakpoints are 1020px and 767px. How would I integrate this into the code so I can specify the sizes for the smaller browsers?

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
    var state = true;
    $( ".map a" ).on( "click", function() {
      if ( state ) {
        $( ".map" ).animate({
          height: 500,
    width: "100%"
        }, 500 );
      } else {
        $( ".map" ).animate({
          height: 349,
    width: "50%"
        }, 1000 );
      }
      state = !state;
    });
  } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css transition combined with media query will make it easier :
Create your default class and your extended class in css, then you just have to add or remove extended class on your element ([`toggleClass();`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) take care of it for you)
You can then define whatever you want as width and height in your media queries depending on resolution

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".map a" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".map" ).toggleClass("extended");
     });
  } );
```

```css
.map{
  height:349px;
  width:50%;
  border:solid 1px red;
  transition : height 1s, width 1s;
}

.map.extended{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px)  {
.map.extended{
  height:20px;
  width:80%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="map"><a>click me</a></div>
```

see here for prefixe and compatibility :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

and here you have samples of Media queries for resolutions 
https://gist.github.com/Mikodes/be9b9ce42e46c3d4ccb6